# What is a "big pawn"?

Tags: pawns, terminology, pieces

I've seen the term "big pawn" come up a few times (such as [here](https://www.chess.com/blog/Spektrowski/the-big-pawn-breakthrough) and [here](https://www.chess.com/forum/view/more-puzzles/big-pawn-on-c2)), but I can't seem to trace down an exact definition. What is it?

Comment: In your first example it's the *breakthrough* that is big, not any of the pawns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A piece (often a bad bishop, but in your second example a queen) which is doing nothing more than protecting a few squares is often called a big pawn. To be honest, I don't find your second example a real case of a 'big pawn', because the queen can easily move away and do something useful. And, as Dag Oskar Madsen mentions, in the first example the *pawn breakthrough* is big, not the pawn itself.

In the position below, the white bishop is a typical example of a big pawn, because of Black's dominance on the dark squares:

```
[FEN "r4r2/5pkp/1q1pb1p1/2p1n3/2P1P3/1P3P2/2BN2PP/1R1Q1RK1 b - - 0 1"]
```

Comment: "In the position below, the white bishop is a typical example of a big pawn", so a bishop can be a big pawn?

Answer (score 6):

The term *big pawn* is usually used to mean an ineffective bishop trapped behind its own pawns. An example from the game Charousek-Maroczy, Budapest 1895:

```
[FEN "6rk/1pp3p1/1r3p1p/p3nP1P/P1PpP3/1P1P4/2B1K1R1/6R1 w - - 0 1"]
```

In this position, the white bishop is just doing the work of a pawn and doesn't have any bigger prospects.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, the first one refers to the amount and importance of pawn play throughout that game.

The second example seems to be making a joke about how the Queen is so ineffective in its position that it might as well be a pawn. If you play through the puzzle you see that it is not able to prevent the sequence.